# Conflict transaction with setTimeout and click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a slider however when I click on the links to go to each slider before finishing the transition has a conflict, is going from one side to another usually works only when I click after the transition.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vv06805/4/)

jquery

```
var currentSlider = 0;

$('.next').click(function(e) {
    if (currentSlider != 1) {
        $('.item').each(function(index, value) {
            var currLeft = parseInt($(value).css('margin-left'));
            var newLeft = currLeft - ($(window).innerWidth());
            $(value).css('margin-left', newLeft + 'px');
        });
        currentSlider += 1;
    };
});

$('.previous').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (currentSlider != -2) {
        $('.item').each(function(index, value) {
            var currLeft = parseInt($(value).css('margin-left'));
            var newLeft = currLeft + ($(window).innerWidth());
            $(value).css('margin-left', newLeft + 'px');

        });

        currentSlider -= 1;
    };
});

function bar(clickedIndex, depth) {
    if (currentSlider < clickedIndex) {
        $(".next").click();
    } else if (currentSlider > clickedIndex) {
        $(".previous").click();
    } else {
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        bar(clickedIndex, depth + 1);
    }, 2005);
}

$("#foo > li > a").click(function(e) {
    bar($(this).data("index"), 0);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: How do you see the desired interaction? Do you queue up the clicks or ignore them until the transition has finished?

Comment: Hi Jack, the transition this conflicting clicks, I already tried to stop the spread every way but was unable. I need the click is disabled when the transition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vv06805/9/

Here's a breakdown of what's been changed:

**Disabling clicks during transition**

To disable clicks, we need a flag of some sort. For this, I just set a simple variable:

```
// Transition flag
var isTransitioning = false;
```

In our click events, we check against that variable to determine if the logic should occur. Here's the updated click logic:

```
$('.next').click(function(e) {
    if (currentSlider != 1) {
        if (transisionsSupported && !isTransitioning) {
            isTransitioning = true;
            $('.item').each(function(index, value) {
                var currLeft = parseInt($(value).css('margin-left'));
                var newLeft = currLeft - ($(window).innerWidth());
                $(value).css('margin-left', newLeft + 'px');
            });
            currentSlider += 1;
        }
    };
});
```

You'll notice in our `if (transitionsSupported && !isTransitioning) {` block, we check `!isTransitioning`, or if we're not transitioning. You'll also see a `transitionsSupported` check, which is a helper function I added.

```
// Helper function to determine transition support
var transitionsSupported = (function() {
        var doc = document.body || document.documentElement,
            style = doc.style,
            vendors = ['webkit', 'Webkit', 'Moz', 'Khtml', 'O', 'ms'],
            i;
        // Test for standard prop
        if (typeof style.transition === 'string') {
            return true;
        }
        // Tests for vendor specific prop
        for (i = 0; i < vendors.length; i++) {
            if (typeof style[vendors[i] + 'Transition'] === 'string') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }());
```

It's a self executing function that only runs once.

Back to our click event, we'll see that we set the `isTransitioning` variable to `true`. Where do we set it back to `false`? In a `transitionEnd` event!

**TransitionEnd event**

```
// Transition end listener, reset flag
if (transisionsSupported) {
    $('.container').on('webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend transitionend', function() {
        isTransitioning = false;
    });
}
```

And that is really it! These additions will prevent you from clicking the next/previous buttons while transitioning is occurring. However, it also interferes with the `bar` function (since clicks are triggered), so you may want to look into that logic.

Hope this helps!